# torch application android

Tags: android, camera

hi i want to implement torch application in android so here is my code

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    camera = Camera.open();
    if(camera == null)
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"CAMERA FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"camera opened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(camera!=null)
                {
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"came to volume up",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                     params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON );
                     camera.setParameters(params);

                }
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF );
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"came to volume down",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

}

why this code is not working???

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: What exactly isn't working about it.  Is it throwing an error?  Is it getting into the Key Event listener?  You've got a lot of real estate in there, it'd be helpful to isolate what really is going wrong.

Comment: no i havent got any error messages...and it is going to events as well but the problem is i couldnt make flash on and off with my code

Comment: eventhough i am pressing volumeup button the flash is not switching on...please tell where i am doing wrong

Comment: You will have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api

hope it works

Comment: You will have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api

hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durga,

I believe you want [`FLASH_MODE_TORCH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_TORCH) not [`FLASH_MODE_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_ON) when you press the volume up key.

Perhaps the following permissions may be required: [`FLASHLIGHT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#FLASHLIGHT) and [`CAMERA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAMERA)

Comment: i have tried FLASH_MODE_TORCH also but it didnt worked.and showing an error when i am pressing volume up or volume down in the logcat....the error shown when i am pressing volume up is ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(95): Unexpected Flash Mode on Hal : -1
ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(95): Set zoom=1 mZoom=1   and the error when i am pressing volume down is ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(95): Set zoom=1 mZoom=1  can you tell me why these errors are coming??

Comment: added permissions you may require, other than that perhaps your hardware doesn't support it?  what phone are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

For Samsung you're required to have a surface view for the camera preview inorder for the torch mode to work.

DID you get it to work yet?

Comment: Have a class that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceView.Callback. In teh constructor, add a callback to the holder and set its type to PUSH_BUFFERS.

For this class, initialize your Camera object in the surfaceCreated method and set your camera parameters there. 

In the surfaceDestroy, release camera object.

In addition, implement additional methods to determine if Samsung device have LED and device LED is lit.

In your activity, declare your surface view object add it to your layout, then setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

Have a class that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceView.Callback. In teh constructor, add a callback to the holder and set its type to PUSH_BUFFERS.

For this class, initialize your Camera object in the surfaceCreated method and set your camera parameters there.

In the surfaceDestroy, release camera object.

In addition, implement additional methods to determine if Samsung device have LED and device LED is lit.

In your activity, declare your surface view object add it to your layout, then setContentView.

Comment: did you mean SurfaceHolder.Callback ?

Answer (score 0):

William Tate was correct saying that you need FLASH_MODE_TORCH along with the two permissions, but the camera hardware doesn't get touched until you start a video preview.

This code will turn on the torch (though you may want to do some error catching in your actual app):

```
Camera c = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
c.setParameters(p);
c.startPreview();
```

And the properly formatted permissions will look like this in your android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```