# Opening Flashlight of Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an app which needs to open the flashlight of my Galaxy Nexus device. I have referred to the post here

[LED flashlight on Galaxy Nexus controllable by what API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api)

```
public class TestCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
Camera mCamera;
public static SurfaceView preview;
public static SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camSurface);
    mHolder = preview.getHolder();
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button onLEDbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onLED_btn);
    onLEDbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);      
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    });
}



}


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mHolder = holder;
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mCamera.stopPreview();
            mHolder = null;
    }




}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

However, I still cant switch on the flashlight. Could anyone point out my errors? Thanks

Comment: you can find everything in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to use the flashlight in Galaxy Nexus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731285/unable-to-use-the-flashlight-in-galaxy-nexus)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>

Above is my manifest file
Moreover, I added the camSurface view inside main.xml
Will it be a problem?
I can get the toast message but cannot switch on the flashlight...
Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: Solved!
mHolder.addCallback(this);
should be add after 
mHolder = preview.getHolder();

Comment: you should accept the answer below

Answer (score 7):

you must to set call back 
mHolder.addCallback(this);

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash
```

And look this post : 
[How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I have the following manifest

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
  <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
             android:protectionLevel="normal"
 />

However it does not work.

Comment: i've found this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505945/led-flashlight-does-not-work-on-samsung-galaxy-nexus

Comment: and this one : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api/9379765#9379765

Comment: I have followed these posts to develop my app. However, it does not work

Comment: I think I could not help you more than that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this tag in manifest file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
```