# RuntimeException startpreview failed

Tags: android, opencv

When i try to run **opencv(2.4.2)** sample3 on **android 4.1.1(galaxy nexus)**. i'm getting RuntimeException. Logcat points  here: `(android.hardware.Camera) mCamera.startPreview();`

If i run same sample on **android 2.3.6(htc hd2)** there is no problem and it works.
Is there any idea how can i fix this problem? I search it and people generally say "*it's not working on android 4.1.1*" but i'm just wondering is there anyone who works it on **android 4.1.1**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not about opencv. Some devices need a SurfaceView to turn on the camera. For more details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9379765/989151).

Comment: well, thanks for the answer, I think I got exactly the same problem with you after I upgrade my phone to 4.3. would you kindly tell me more specifically what's going on and how to fix this? I am new to android things and works with jni mostly. Thanks again.

Comment: After I asked this question long time passed so i don't remember very well but i guess if you turn on camera on your application check what layout you're using for camera view? It should be SurfaceView as i wrote before