# how Flash LED on and off in android?

Tags: android, flash, camera, led

i want to on and off LED or flash of android phone programmatically but in Samsung Google nexus the flash is not on. i use many methods for it but can't get good result.

```
 Camera mycam = Camera.open();
                 Parameters p = mycam.getParameters();
                 p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                 mycam.setParameters(p);
```

i use these codes and also give all permission but the problem is same that it not work on Samsung google nexus.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14027376/2024761)

Comment: i found [this link][1] and get help from it. it really help me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one , it's may help you :

```
private void flashOn() {
        camera = Camera.open();
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        // Build.MODEL.equals("GT-P1000")
        if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("SAMSUNG")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("LG"))
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        else
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void flashOff() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        }
    }
```

and add this in your manifest file :

```
<permission
        android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```