# Flashlight Only turns On for less than a second

Tags: android, flashlight, motorola-droid

I'm using the following code but the flashlight would just on for less then a second when i press the button.

I'm Using **Motorola XT907**

```
Camera  cam;
cam = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: your code looks fine. but just in case take a look at this : https://github.com/p4yam/GushiYab/blob/master/java/ir/kivee/gushiyab/OnCallActivity.java#L42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLVED***

Somehow using the SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder class solved the problem for me

Code is described in the following thread.

[LED flashlight on Galaxy Nexus controllable by what API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api/9379765#9379765)