# Controlling Flashlight in All Android devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, flashlight, android-compatibility

I'm using Camera Package for developing android app to turn on flash light, like this:

```
    Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
    List<String> flashModes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
    if(flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)){
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    } else if (flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)){
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
    if(!previewing){
        mCamera.startPreview();
        previewing = true;
    }
```

It check supporting camera flash modes, and adjust it. It works in Samsung Android devices, and some others, but doesn't works in LG V20, LG V30 and Mi Android. I searched for this and tried:

```
mCamera.autoFocus(Camera.AutoFocusCallback)
mCamera.setPreviewTexture(SurfaceTexture)
```

But nothing works. So I used Camera2 package for api>23, like:

```
CameraManager mCameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
mCameraManager.setTorchMode("0", true);
```

And it works, but in Samsung device, an notification show up "Flashlight turned on" and it's very annoying.

So, I need the way to turn on flashlight for all devices with Camera package, or not to show up "Flashlight turned on" notification using Camera2 package.

I look forward to your reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in below link saves my life!

The SurfaceView is essential for some devices.

[LED flashlight on Galaxy Nexus controllable by what API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876843/led-flashlight-on-galaxy-nexus-controllable-by-what-api)